# HttpSecurity configuration problems in spring-security-oauth2

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm pretty new with Spring, and I'm trying to build an OAuth Server using spring-security-oauth2.

I mainly refered to the sample and a tutorial given by spring.io.

> https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/samples/oauth2
>   http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

However, I face some problems about `HttpSecurity` configuration.

My folder structure is as follow.

```
├─java
│  └─com
│      └─example
│              Greeting.java
│              GreetingController.java
│              MvcConfig.java
│              OAuth2ServerConfig.java
│              SecurityConfig.java
│              SocialApplication.java
│
└─resources
    │  application.yml
    │
    └─templates
            hello.html
            home.html
            login.html
```

I add some `HttpSecurity` configuration in `SecurityConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll();
    }
}
```

OK, it works fine. However, I want to protect the `greeting` api (which is a simple rest api I just copied from another demo) in my `Resource Server`.
So I add some `HttpSecurity` configuration in `OAuth2ServerConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/greeting")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().access("#oauth2.hasScope('scope1')");
        // @formatter:on
    }

}
```

It seems that I only protect `/greeting`. However, when this was done, I can't even access `/` and `/login`. It said that `Full authentication is required to access this resource`.

Did I miss some configuration or do anything wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Well, I find the solution.
The situation is mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/634).
It's a bug in Spring-Security 4.0.3.

The way to solve it is just use `requestMatcher()` instead of `requestMatchers()` when config your `Resource Server`.
Here is an example.

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
              .requestMatcher(
                  new OrRequestMatcher(
                      new AntPathRequestMatcher("/greeting"),
                      new AntPathRequestMatcher("/greeting2")
                  )
              )
              .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers("/greeting").access("#oauth2.hasScope('scope1')")
              .antMatchers("/greeting2").access("#oauth2.hasScope('scope2')");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the same issues before.

To solve it, I replaced `requestMatchers().antMatchers(...).and()` with `antMatcher(...)`

Please try the configuration below:

```
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http
        .antMatcher("/greeting")
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().access("#oauth2.hasScope('scope1')");
    // @formatter:on
}
```

Comment: Oh, it actually works! So if I want to protect a lot of resource, I just need to use `.and()` between each `.antMatcher()`?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the `anyRequest().access("#oauth2.hasScope('scope1')");` In your `ResourceServerConfiguration` every request needs to be authenticated with an OAuth scope, including `/` and `/login` (Because the OAuth security configuration comes after the normal configuration in the Spring Security Chain). If you want to protect `/greeting` with OAuth you should something like this in your `ResourceServerConfiguration`:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/greeting").authenticated();
    // @formatter:on
}
```

Comment: I change the code as you said. `/greeting` is protected now, but my configuration in `SecurityConfig.java` doesn't work. I can access `/hello` without login.

Comment: And you couldn't before you added the OAuth configuration?

Comment: I couldn't, when I try to access `/hello` without login, it should redirect to `/login`, as I configured in `SecurityConfig.java`.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same problem and the accepted answer did solve the issue. However, the current solution should be to use `spring-security-oauth2` version `2.0.9.RELEASE`. This version includes [a fix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/commit/21fce68a2a28794e7627f8e25500e760b352e349) that should work in both Spring Security 3.2 and 4.0.

Comment: This should have been a comment under the answer, but thanks for letting the community know.